# Jmeter websockets testing - Illegal character in query

Tags: jmeter

I'm getting this error when executing script:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 65: https://devadmin.modetrans.com/fusionsocket?Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, br&Accept-Language=en-US,en;q=0.9&Cache-Control=no-cache&Connection=Upgrade&Host=rtdev.service.signalr.net&Origin=https://devfront.modetrans.com&Pragma=no-cache&Sec-WebSocket-Extensions=permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits&Sec-WebSocket-Key=sr0WkpBGbtlraMcYZZkLLQ==&Sec-WebSocket-Version=13&Upgrade=websocket&User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/
```

Jmeter settings:
[image: JMeter settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is wrong, you should put only `devadmin.modetrans.com` bit to the "Server Name or IP" field of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler like:

[image]

You might also be interested in [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide/) which explains the usage of the [JMeter WebSocket Samplers](https://github.com/ptrd/jmeter-websocket-samplers) plugin (the same limitations apply there as well, only valid [DNS hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) is accepted in the "Server Name or IP" field